# Why MemoryStream() has data even though it is not initialized with any source of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memorystream

I have a test `.Net Core` application and I want to read http responses from pipeline for my personal practice.

This minimum code example provides http response. I know it is destroying the response body which I need to fix it latter, but it is not my question. My question is how does `MemoryStream()` has http response inside it even though I didn't initialized it with any source of data?

`"Startup.cs"`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        using (var swapStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = swapStream;

            await next.Invoke();

            swapStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string responseBody = new StreamReader(swapStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
    });
 }
```

As you can see `MemoryStream()` is not initialized with any source of data at all. But in the end in `responseBody` I can see my http response. What makes me more confused is that if I remove `context.Response.Body = swapStream;` then I don't have http response in `responseBody`.

It would be appreciated if someone could help me to understand how does this code works.

Comment: Why do you believe this situation is wrong?

Comment: await next.Invoke() ?

Comment: You need to read up on middleware in ASP.Net Core. It will make it clearer what is happening. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Llama Because according to my programming knowledge I expect `swapStream` should be initialized with `context.Response.Body`. I haven't done this and instead `context.Response.Body` is destroyed with `context.Response.Body = swapStream;`. But still it is working and it made me confused.

Comment: _"`context.Response.Body` is destroyed with `context.Response.Body = swapStream;`"_ - No it isn't. You've replaced the `Stream`, which is written to when serving the response, with `swapStream`. The left side of an assignment receives whatever the right side gives it. The right-side doesn't change based on the left side. You have that the wrong away around. IN the same way that `string responseBody = new StreamReader(swapStream).ReadToEnd();` doesn't (somehow) set `new StreamReader(swapStream).ReadToEnd();` to the value of `responseBody`.

Comment: @Llama Thank you very much. I had a hard time but finally I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something else is writing to the stream, it happens when you call

```
await next.Invoke();
```

You are replacing the response stream with your memorystream, and something later in the chain writes to that stream.